# PHP XML simple variable problem

Tags: php, xml

I would like to change the 4c050652f0c3e ( of `<testimonial id="xxx">` ) to a dynamic variable that it is sent through a form. 
My variable is `$nodeid = $_POST['nodeid'];` but i can not replace it right.

**This is the code**

```
foreach( $testimonials->xpath("testimonial[@id='4c050652f0c3e']") as $t ) {
  $t->$_POST['tagname'] = $_POST['newname'];
}
```

**This is what I did but it is not right**

```
foreach( $testimonials->xpath("testimonial[@id=$_POST['nodeid']]") as $t ) {
  $t->$_POST['tagname'] = $_POST['newname'];
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: shouldnt a xpath exp. start with "//"?

Comment: @MrQ.C. no, that's just telling the XPath expression to match anywhere in the document, which is not necessarily what's wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add `'`

```
foreach( $testimonials->xpath("testimonial[@id='".$_POST['nodeid']]."'") as $t ) {
  $t->$_POST['tagname'] = $_POST['newname'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

foreach works on a copy of your array, so this would not work. You could use a different loop (for loop?), or use references to the array

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach( $testimonials->xpath("testimonial[@id='".$_POST['nodeid']."']") as $t ) {
  $t->$_POST['tagname'] = $_POST['newname'];
}
```